# mod_rewrite to 302 a blank query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently working with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /somepath

RewriteRule ^/$ home [R]
```

I'd like to have requests of `GET /somepath` to redirect via 302 to `/somepath/home`. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is working on a subdirectory of the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using mod_rewrite in an .htaccess file, the base path is removed from the requested URL path before testing the patterns. That means `/somepath` (or rather `/somepath/`, since you’re actually in `/somepath/`) is removed so that the remaining path is empty. So:

```
RewriteRule ^$ home [R]
```